# Complex literal 'i' used in function argument

Tags: c++, std, complex-numbers

There seems to be a problem, using the [literal `i`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) in C++ with `std::complex`.

Consider the following code:

```
std::complex<double> a = -1.0i * 42.0;
std::complex<double> b = a + 1.0i;
```

The second line fails to compile with:
`error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::complex<double>’ and ‘__complex__ double’)`

This also shows up when using the complex literal in function calls, e.g.

```
std::exp<std::complex<double>>( 1.0i * 3.14159 );
```

How come the complex literal `1.0i` is not convertible to `std::complex<double>`?

Do I have to explicitly construct a `std::complex` with `1.0i`?

Comment: Which compiler and version? This compiles for me on GCC trunk, Clang trunk, and a slightly older version of MSVC.

Comment: For example, ideone's gcc 6.3, as shown here : https://ideone.com/qxw5eI

Comment: Somehow it [compiles fine on wandbox's gcc 6.3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/abhwVsce4CsOLZGG)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should recompile with `--std=c++14` (no GNU ext) to avoid conflict of `i` suffix with [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html#Complex)

> The ISO C++14 library also defines the ‘i’ suffix, so C++14 code that includes the `<complex>` header cannot use ‘i’ for the GNU extension. The ‘j’ suffix still has the GNU meaning.